# How to load tables with static content in production environment with symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

#### Scenario

We want to autofill a table with new static content with doctrine, ideally with something like a fixture class or similar.

We follow the simple development life-cycle with *development* to *staging* to *production*. And we are using **Doctrine v2.6 with Symfony v3.4**. Every release step is executed by an Jenkins job.

For *development* and *staging* we use the very useful and simple `doctrine-fixtures-bundle` to auto-fill our database with test-datasets. The database-schema is auto-generated by `doctrine:schema:update` on basis of our entities.

I've tried to use the fixtures also for production but even with `doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/MyBundle/DataFixture/ORM/MyFixture.php` it is purging the whole database. Then I read something about the `--append` command to prevent doctrine from purging the database. But then it will append the datasets in every release process (?). Nevertheless, it also feels like a very bad practice.

#### What I'm wondering

Is it possible to truncate the table, load table records with static data loaded from a class that can be executed via a command line? Or is there a completely different (and clean) way for such a case? Is the `doctrine:migration` bundle the real way to go?

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: why are you not writing [migrations](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)? They exist for the purpose of updating production environments on deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Command for populate tables.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html